# Auto join a python dataframe to update it

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I would like to perform an auto-join on a python dataframe to update it.
Here is the situation, I have a first df with three columns:
In, Out & Date. It means that at a specific date the item "Out" is replaced by "In".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
data = [[1,10,"2017-01-01"],[2,10,"2017-01-01"],[10,11,"2017-06-01"],[4,14,"2017-04-01"],[5,14,"2017-12-01"]]
label = ["Out","In","Date"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=label)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df)

   Out  In       Date
0    1  10 2017-01-01
1    2  10 2017-01-01
2   10  11 2017-06-01
3    4  14 2017-04-01
4    5  14 2017-12-01
```

For example it means here that as of first of Jan 2017, item #1 is replaced by item #10. 
The trick is that as of june 2017, this item #10 is also replaced by item #11. So that #1 becomes #10 that becomes #11.

Now I would like to populate a final table that gives the final relationships up to a certain date.

If date = 2017-08-01, I would get this table

```
date = pd.to_datetime("2017-08-01")
data = [[1,11],[2,11],[10,11],[4,14]]
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Out","In"])
print(df_final)

   Out  In
0   1   11
1   2   11
2  10   11
3   4   14
```

Would you know how to perform such an auto join?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use List comprehension methods and .loc to locate the values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
data = [[1,10,"2017-01-01"],[2,10,"2017-01-01"],[10,11,"2017-06-01"],[4,14,"2017-04-01"],[5,14,"2017-12-01"],[11,18,"2017-12-01"]]
label = ["Out","In","Date"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=label)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df)

   Out  In       Date
0    1  10    2017-01-01
1    2  10     2017-01-01
2   10  11     2017-06-01
3    4  14     2017-04-01
4    5  14     2017-12-01
5   11  18     2017-12-01

L=[]
for row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[1]['Out']
    y = row[1]['In']
    while y in df.Out.values.tolist():
        y = df.loc[df['Out'] == y,'In'].iloc[0]
    L.append((x,y))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Out', 'In'])
print(df2)

Out  In
1    18
2    18
10   18
4    14
5    14
11   18
```

Comment: Hello S Ringne, this works thank you. I've added a filter on "Date" to only select the right combinations.

Comment: @Nicolas Cool :) I overlooked at the date part.Please accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: The thing I am still struggling with is to find the most up to date combination. For example what if you still have 11 -> 12. Then your code won't work. I am working on it, but still struggling. In my real dataset I need to rerun your loop 6 times to find each time the most up to date value. I am trying to create a for loop that gets the most up to date value for each line

Comment: So I am using your solution with just an extra filter. But to make sure to go for the most up to date version, I would like to put "    try:
        y = df.loc[df['Out'] == y,'In'].iloc[0]" into a loop. Is it possible to do so with a while for example?

Comment: @Nicolas: See Edit

Comment: Awesome! Shouldn't I change "   try:
        y = df.loc[df['Out'] == y,'In'].iloc[0]
        if y in df.Out.values.tolist():
            y = df.loc[df['Out'] == y,'In'].iloc[0]" by just "while y in df.Out.values.tolist(): y = df.loc[df['Out'] == y,'In'].iloc[0]" ?

Comment: @Nicolas The answer provided specifically addresses to the nature of the question. You can modify the code accordingly to suit your convenience.
As a common practice in stack overflow,you should tick mark the answer if it helps you.